# AWS OpsWorks cookbook error at s3.rb

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I was creating an AWS OpsWorks stack and then got this error:

```
[2016-02-23T00:25:05+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[create git repository] action run (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 58)

================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[create git repository]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.' ----
STDOUT: Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/opsworks20160223-1192-1ursi1c/archive.d/.git/
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit
STDERR: 
---- End output of find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.' ----
Ran find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.' returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/scm_helper/libraries/s3.rb

58:         execute 'create git repository' do
59:           cwd "#{tmpdir}/archive.d"
60:           command "find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \\;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \\;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.'"
61:         end
62: 
63:         "#{tmpdir}/archive.d"
64:       end
65:     end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/scm_helper/libraries/s3.rb:58:in `prepare_s3_checkouts'

execute("create git repository") do
action "run"
retries 0
retry_delay 2
command "find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \\;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \\;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.'"
backup 5
cwd "/tmp/opsworks20160223-1192-1ursi1c/archive.d"
returns 0
cookbook_name "opsworks_custom_cookbooks"
recipe_name "checkout"
end
```

There's something wrong about the `find` command that it returns code 1 which makes the stack failed.

What am I missing? I'm new to Chef and Opsworks, any advice? Thanks

Comment: Nothing to do with the find command IMO, but out of pure vacuum like this it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: This was just AWS preconfig setup, it's kind of impossible to debug

Comment: OpsWorks has its own way of using chef,not always easy to debug with usual chef knowledge, pinging @coderanger which may have a better insight on this

Answer (score 0):

It looks your S3 archive file is empty. You may try again with S3 archive with files inside it.